# Convert register values to float 32 big endian

Tags: c#, .net, floating-point, modbus, modbus-tcp

I have two signed register values 17147 and -27394. They are in order of High-Low bits. I want to get the value float 32 big endian value using these value. I have used following code to convert to value.

My code

```
int intValue = 17147;
intValue <<= 16;
intValue += -27394;
byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(intValue);
double readingValue = BitConverter.ToSingle(bytes, 0);
```

According to above code reading shows as **125.291**. But modbus tools & other online convertions says that value should be **125.791**.

Please note that some times reading is okay for some values. Actual value and converted value difference is not the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're combining the two registers together incorrectly.

- 17147 is hex `42 FB` (or `00 00 42 FB` as a 4-byte value)
- -27394 is hex `94 FE` as a 2-byte value, or `FF FF 94 FE` as a 4-byte value
- Therefore `intValue` should have the hex value `42 FB 94 FE`, but your way of combining `42 FB` and `94 FE` gives you `42 FA 94 FE`.

You're being caught out by the fact that -27394 is presented as a negative number, but that's just the way that your software has chosen to interpret those 2 bytes. You're then treating it as a signed 4-byte value rather than an unsigned 2-byte value when you come to combine it with the 17147.

When we combine 17147 and -27394, we need to make sure that we just look at the lower 2 bytes of each. That will undo any damage that was done by interpreting the values as signed 4-byte numbers.

```
int upper = 17147;
int lower = -27394;
int intValue = ((upper & 0xFFFF) << 16) | (lower & 0xFFFF);
```

Now:

```
byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(intValue);
double readingValue = BitConverter.ToSingle(bytes, 0);
Console.WriteLine(readingValue);
```

Gives 125.79100036621094, as expected.

Comment: Side note - probably there is no reason to convert that 32-bit float we obtained to 64-bit double.

Comment: There's no harm though - it's a lossless conversion. And most floating-point C# code outside of game dev uses double, so it's probably lower friction than keeping it as a float.